# tag merge: multi-tenant, multi-tenancy and multitenancy

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[multi-tenant](/questions/tagged/multi-tenant) is by far the most popular so I think it should be the only one, with [multitenancy](/questions/tagged/multitenancy) and [multi-tenancy](/questions/tagged/multi-tenancy) as synonyms

[Administration of a Multi-Tenant Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583947/administration-of-a-multi-tenant-rails-app) is a classic, with all 3 tags...

A single tag would really help me right now to search for [django] [multi-tenant]

Comment: I don't know specifics here, but *sometimes* identical-looking tags are used for slightly different things (for example similar libraries in different languages). Is this the case here, or are they *really* synonymous?

Comment: From what I know of multi-tenant it's simply the adjective (and by far the more common term) for multi-tenancy.  In my view they can be safely merged into multi-tenant.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy uses both terms as noun and adjective for the same concept.

Comment: I'd be inclined to synonymize to multi-tenancy.  It's what the Wikipedia article calls it, and multi-tenant is probably popular because it was the first tag created.

Comment: Multi-tenant is a much more common term - started hearing it about a decade ago, whereas multi-tenancy only cropped up for me more recently.  So I think multi-tenant is oldest because it's the earlier term, and still current.